# Parse Android Kernel /dev/input/event touch information

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I've been playing around with the Android Kernel input for a while now and I want to build a script that executes actions when a certain pattern on the screen is drawn, no matter what the phone is doing in that instant.
So, my idea was to directly capture the touchscreen input from `dev/input/event3/` and store it in a file that will be scanned by another script in a given interval to detect if it contains a certain pattern.

I've been logging the touchscreen input data via `getevent event3` and sorted out the values I need and I've been able to match these values to the output of `cat event3` that I use to directly get the input data. (I **have** to use the raw cat output, since getevent apparently is too slow, at least `getevent event3 > test.log` does **not** work)

The problem is, using `getevent`, I get reasonable X/Y coordinates that I can use to match a pattern, however, using the raw cat outpu, the X/Y values are seemingly random!

```
dcf4 0100 08b2 0800 0300 3500 3c01 0000
dcf4 0100 27b2 0800 0300 3600 1d04 0000
dcf4 0100 831e 0900 0300 3500 3f01 0000
dcf4 0100 a21e 0900 0300 3600 1604 0000
dcf4 0100 d7ea 0900 0300 3500 7701 0000

[dcf4 0100 d7ea 0900][0300][3600][c903 0000]
[timestamp          ][type][parm][value    ]
```

Looking over the [kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L24), I found that struct, which would match the output pattern, except for a missing timestamp value. However, assuming that the last 8 characters here are just a `int32_t`, the input makes absolutely no sense.

**My question is**: If this is a `int32_t`, why is its value nothing like the actual X/Y position I touch? - Or otherwise, **how do I get the correct X/Y value out of that data?**